# How to generate searchable PDF using swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdf-generation

Right now I am able to generate a PDF using the code below. The issue is that the generated PDF is not searchable nor its texts copyable. (like the whole PDF is a image).

Is there a way to create a PDF using ios (Swift) that has its texts copyable/searchable?

Part of my code that generates the pdf:

```
let pdfFrame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sourceView.contentSize.width, height: sourceView.contentSize.height);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(dataFilename, pdfFrame, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfFrame, nil);

sourceView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero;
sourceView.frame = pdfFrame;
let pdfContext : CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!;
sourceView.layer.render(in: pdfContext);

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to generate a PDF that is searchable, you need to create a PDF file that contains text. Your PDF is being created only with images. You can't use `render(in:)`. Whatever text you want in the PDF needs to be drawn into the PDF context. See [How to draw text in PDF context in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113468/how-to-draw-text-in-pdf-context-in-swift) for an example.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and up-vote your answer if it works.