# Swift 4 - NSGraphicsContext.setCurrent() has no member 'setCurrent'

Tags: swift, pdf, swift4, quartz-graphics

So I am trying to overlay text onto a PDF document using a similar method to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640022/draw-on-a-pdf-using-swift-on-macos).

I use a function to set the current Graphics Context, like it says to in the documentation.

```
let pdfPage: CGPDFPage = pdf.page(at: 1)!
            //var pageRect = pdfPage.getBoxRect(CGPDFBox.mediaBox)
            //print(pageRect)

            let doc: PDFDocument = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL!)!
            let page: PDFPage = doc.page(at: 0)!
            var mediaBox: CGRect = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)

            let context = CGContext(destinationURL as CFURL, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)
            let graphicsContext = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: context!, flipped: false)
            NSGraphicsContext.setCurrent(graphicsContext)

            context!.beginPDFPage(nil)

            page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context!)

            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.alignment = .center

            let richText = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, world!", attributes: [
                NSAttributedStringKey.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 64),
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.red,
                NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: style
                ])

            let richTextBounds = richText.size()
            let point = CGPoint(x: mediaBox.midX - richTextBounds.width / 2, y: mediaBox.midY - richTextBounds.height / 2)

            context!.saveGState()
            do {
                context!.translateBy(x: point.x, y: point.y)
                context!.rotate(by: .pi / 5)
                richText.draw(at: .zero)
            }
            context!.restoreGState()



            context!.endPDFPage()
            NSGraphicsContext.setCurrent(nil)
            context?.closePDF()
        }
```

And the line:

```
NSGraphicsContext.setCurrent(graphicsContext)
```

Throws an error that says "Type 'NSGraphicsContext' has no member 'setCurrent'"

Anyone have any ideas on what's going on?  Is there something I'm missing in terms of a framework?

Comment: I updated the linked answer two days ago to use the current syntax. (@rmaddy's answer is also correct.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `current` class property.

```
NSGraphicsContext.current = graphicsContext
```

Comment: worked like a dream.  thank you.  I should have been able to figure that out :/