# How to add a link annotation with a PDFActionGoto action type to a PDFPage using swift in MACOS

Tags: macos, swift5, pdfkit

I have been trying to add a link annotation to my PDFPage so that once clicked it will take me to a specific location of the next page. This is the way I am trying but my code is not working:

1. The cursor does not change to the pointer style.
2. Once the area is clicked navigation does not occur.
3. .freetext annotation is working and getting displayed.

I would appreciate any help regarding this. I have been trying this for the last couple of days. I am using latest version of xcode (12 and swift 5.3)

```
    let docDirectoryPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]


    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
    let page1 = PDFPage()
    let page2 = PDFPage()
    pdfDocument.insert(page1, at: 0)
    pdfDocument.insert(page2, at: 1)
    
    let textAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: NSRect(x: 200, y: 1000, width: 600, height: 25), forType: .freeText, withProperties: nil)
    textAnnotation.contents = "Click me to go to the next page"
    
    let linkAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: NSRect(x: 200, y: 1000, width: 600, height: 25), forType: .link, withProperties: nil)
    linkAnnotation.action = PDFActionGoTo(destination: PDFDestination(page: page2, at: NSPoint(x: 200, y: 1000)))
    linkAnnotation.shouldDisplay = true
    linkAnnotation.shouldPrint = true

    let someText = PDFAnnotation(bounds: NSRect(x: 200, y: 1000, width: 600, height: 25), forType: .freeText, withProperties: nil)
    someText.contents = "This is the desitnation of link annotation"

    page1.addAnnotation(textAnnotation)
    page1.addAnnotation(linkAnnotation)
    page2.addAnnotation(someText)

    
    let printOpts: [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey: Any] = [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobDisposition: NSPrintInfo.JobDisposition.preview, NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobSavingURL: docDirectoryPath]
    
    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printOpts)
    printInfo.horizontalPagination = NSPrintInfo.PaginationMode.automatic
    printInfo.verticalPagination = NSPrintInfo.PaginationMode.automatic
    printInfo.topMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.leftMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.rightMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
    printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = false
    printInfo.paperSize = NSSize(width: 8.5*96, height: 11*96)
    printInfo.scalingFactor =  1.0
    let printOperation = pdfDocument.printOperation(for: printInfo, scalingMode: .pageScaleNone, autoRotate: false)!
    printOperation.showsPrintPanel = true
    printOperation.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error I figured that if the document is run through printOperation linkAnnotation is not retained. So I used save panel to save document to file instead. If you click on the green area of the first page it will take you to the page 2 (Destination Arrived)

```
    import Foundation
    import PDFKit 
    
    let page1 = PDFPage()
    let page2 = PDFPage()
    
    let link = PDFAnnotation(bounds: NSRect(x: 40, y: 750, width: 200, height: 30), forType: .link, withProperties: nil)
    let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: NSRect(x: 40, y: 750, width: 200, height: 30), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
    highlight.color = .green
    highlight.backgroundColor = .red
    
    let text = PDFAnnotation(bounds: NSRect(x: 40, y: 400, width: 200, height: 30), forType: .freeText, withProperties: nil)
    text.contents = "Destination Arrived!"
    link.action = PDFActionGoTo(destination: PDFDestination(page: page2, at: NSPoint(x: 40, y: 430)))
    
    page1.addAnnotation(highlight)
    page1.addAnnotation(link)
    
    page2.addAnnotation(text)
    
    let pdfDoc = PDFDocument()
    pdfDoc.insert(page1, at: 0)
    pdfDoc.insert(page2, at: 1)
    
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
    savePanel.title = NSLocalizedString("Save file", comment: "enableFileMenuItems")
    savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "LinkAnnotation.pdf"
    savePanel.prompt = NSLocalizedString("Save", comment: "enableFileMenuItems")
    savePanel.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf"]
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    savePanel.begin() { (result2) -> Void in
        if result2 == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
            let fileWithExtensionURL = savePanel.url!
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileWithExtensionURL.path) {
            } else {
                pdfDoc.write(to: fileWithExtensionURL)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes: printing a PDF -- even if back to a file -- will lose all metadata like Annotations, ToC, Title, Author, etc.