# How to generate a pdf in swift 3.0 without using HTML

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but what I need precisely is using a **PrintDocument** which is available in C#, which uses C# and not **HTML** to design the document itself. Any extra help which includes linking tutorials will also be much appreciated. Thank you!
For some general context, C# uses *Graphics* variable 'g' to draw elements on the document.

```
g.drawString("Hello", Font, Brush, X, Y)
```

Comment: I assume that you read [Generating PDF Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) from Apple's "Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS"? – Yes, that is Objective-C, but it works the same from Swift: Create a PDF context and draw to it.

Comment: Here is a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113468/how-to-draw-text-in-pdf-context-in-swift.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR I will try these and let you know.